# Log4j2 custom filter not working getting Filters contains an invalid element or attribute

Tags: log4j2

While working with log4j custom filters getting "ERROR Filters contains an invalid element or attribute StringMatchFilter" while tomcat server startup

My class

```
@Plugin(
        name = "StringMatchFilter",
        category = "Core",
        elementType = "filter",
        printObject = true
)
public class StringMatchFilter extends AbstractFilter {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final String VERSION = ModuleVersion
            .register("$Id: StringMatchFilter.java 207693 2016-08-11 23:17:59Z DavisWalsh $");
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5382929677973762187L;

    private boolean acceptOnMatch = true;
    private String stringToMatch;

    public void setStringToMatch(String s) {
        stringToMatch = s;
    }

    public String getStringToMatch() {
        return stringToMatch;
    }

    public void setAcceptOnMatch(boolean acceptOnMatch) {
        this.acceptOnMatch = acceptOnMatch;
    }

    public boolean getAcceptOnMatch() {
        return acceptOnMatch;
    }

    /**
     * Called by log4j to decide if event is to be logged.
     * @param event 
     * @return result
     */
    @Override
    public Result filter(final LogEvent event) {
        String msg = event.getMessage().getFormattedMessage();

        if(msg == null || stringToMatch == null)
            return Result.NEUTRAL;

        if( msg.indexOf(stringToMatch) == -1 ) {
            return Result.NEUTRAL;
        } else { // we've got a match
            if(acceptOnMatch) {
                return Result.ACCEPT;
            } else {
                return Result.DENY;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my log4j2.xml file looks like below

```
<Configuration status="warn" >
<Appenders>
<RollingRandomAccessFile  name="Mytest" fileName="${sys:test.logdir}/TestRULES.log" filePattern="${sys:test.logdir}/TestRULES-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
    <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d [%20.20t] [%10.10X{pegathread}] [%20.20X{tenantid}] [%20.20X{app}] (%30.30c{3}) %-5p %X{stack} %X{userid} - %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
<Filters>

<StringMatchFilter stringToMatch="StringMatchFilter"/>
 </Filters>     
</Appenders>
</Configuration>
```

Can any one help me.
Even for my requirement i'm trying to use in built logger i.e "`<RegexFilter regex=".*MatchFilter.*" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>`", but at run time Filter object not getting initialized. I would like to know is any thing wrong i'm doing?

Comment: Typically, "contains an invalid element or attribute" indicates that your plugin cannot be found. Did you compile with the annotation processor enabled? Do you have the Log4jPlugins.dat file in your project?

Comment: @rgoers Yes i had Log4jPlugins.dat file in my project. But how to compile annotation processor enabled. Is it from IDE or any specific jar dependency has to add?

Comment: If Log4jPlugins.dat was created then it should be working. If you look in that file you should see the definition of your plugin. What version of Java are you using and are you using the module path?

Comment: @rgoers Still it's not working. Even i'm trying to use in built filters like RegexFilter, but not working.Currently i'm using java1.8 and module path from where your referring? If you have any documentation kind of thing can you share. It will help full to me.

Comment: It can't even find the RegexFilter? What version of log4j are you using and which jars have you included? Are they all in your webapp or are some deployed with tomcat?

Comment: @rgoers RegexFilter is identifying, but my custom filter is not working. Is there any filter i can trace the debug log based on the request type. For example if the request is coming from http/web then only it should trace in the log, if any batch request in background for this it should not trace in the log. For this any kind of filter do we have. Can you please help me.

Comment: No, and I don't know how you would identify whether the request is coming from the web vs a batch request unless you put something in the RequestContext at the beginning of the request. You could then use the ThreadContextMapFilter or DynamicThresholdFilter to control logging.

Comment: @rgoers Now My Custom Filter is getting invoked. The problem is PluginFactory is not added to my custom class and package="pkg name" not had in my log4j2.xml. After both changes custom filter is getting invoked.

Comment: I am glad it is working, but package="pkg name" should only be required if Log4j can't find the Log4jPlugins.dat file that describes your plugin.